# Main Menu in Orchard site Showing Twice

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have installed orchard from an existing database and its showing main menu twice in the front site. That's how it looks like in main site

[image]

I have confirmed it from admin navigation that menu has only been defined once.
what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your existing database there are duplicate records. Try to see Content Types in admin panel.